# Views Group By with profile with aggregation and relationship

Tags: views

I am looking for solution for following problem.

**Problem:**

I have "article" content type. 
I have list of some users who are associated with different - 2 roles.

User having role "editor" can create articles. So editors type of user have created number of contents.

Now I need to display a list of featured articles on home page using Views-block with given conditions.

- Every author who have created most articles, his block should come in top of list with his recent one article.
- It should be followed by author name.
- I will show top 10 articles of different - 2 authors with correct author ordering. I mean  author who have created most articles should come on top followed by rest of authors.

**Note:** In this block one author should come once with correct order.

**Resolution:**

- I created views block with filter criteria where content type =
  'article'.
- I enabled aggregation.
- I make relationship with User and in fields choose `COUNT(DISTINCT
  Content: Title) | Aggregation settings` option.
- I choose `Query settings: Distinct`.

I tried above possible solution but unable to get correct result. I am still getting duplicate result and also the order is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [Views Distinct](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_distinct) module. From its project page:

> Relationships or other joins in Views often create "duplicate" results. For example, a node with a field that has multiple values may show up in the View once per value in the multi-value field. It's frustrating, and the "DISTINCT" SQL query option in the Views UI does not actually solve the problem because the result row is technically distinct. This module aims to give a simple GUI method to remove or aggregate these "duplicate" rows.

Curious to hear if this helps to answer this question.